# couchbase - how to use getandlock with php

Tags: php, couchbase

I am using couchbase with php as a temporary database, There will be multiple scripts running simultaneously to fetch and update the value of an object, i want to protect the object from having wrong value at any time, thus implementing lock over object.

I tried to Implemented couchbase getandlock method but the documentation does not clearly how to use it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll want to use is the CAS feature of Couchbase.  The official documentation describes it well:

> This operation is also known as a check-and-set method; it enables you to update information only if a unique identifier matches the identifier for the document you want to change. This identifier, called a CAS value or ID, prevents an application from updating values in the database that may have changed since the application originally obtained the value.

Link to official doc -> http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#check-and-set-cas

You can see an example gist here of using PHP and CAS:

https://gist.github.com/3155132/2301591fa9d2dddbf3c2578ad1369703493c5aef